How is a Solana wallet created behind the hood?
I realize that the private key is generated based on the ed25519 algorithm and that the public key is extrapolated from the private key, but I am wondering how does the actual connection get made between a private key and the Solana network? is every ed25519 generated keypair on the network?
For example, would it work if I were to create an ed25519 private key using OpenSSH and base58 encode it and then import it to phantom?

I believe it is. I like this article on getting some insight on private keys and comparison to Ethereum: https://chainstack.com/how-do-ethereum-and-solana-generate-public-and-private-keys/

You've got it! Unlike EVM where the pubkey still gets hashed and cropped, a Solana keypair is nothing more than a normal ed25519 keypair. Using OpenSSH or any other tool/library that correctly implements ed25519 will be fine for creating a Solana keypair. The exact specification the solana codebase links to is https://blog.mozilla.org/warner/2011/11/29/ed25519-keys/.
Only thing to look out for is that in the case of Solana the private key (or, as they call it, secret key) is defined as consisting of 64 bytes, with the first 32 bytes being the private key and the last 32 bytes being the pubkey.
